# How do you get wireless LAN working on Raspbmc?

Tags: networking, wireless, raspbmc

I have my Raspberry Pi running Raspbmc and all is fine. However, I now need to get the device running on wireless.

I have a RTL8188CU USB wireless adapter, so some searching provided information to change the driver as per the following steps:

```
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80256631/8192cu-20120701.tar.gz
tar xfv 8192cu-20120701.tar.gz
sudo mv 8192cu.ko /lib/modules/3.1.9+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.1.9+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192cu.ko
```

Now I can pass `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning`, and it returns a list of the access points it can see, but I can't get it to connect to any of them.

The instructions then say to follow steps 2/3 in this post:
http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=732 and create a name.ini file. I did that, but it didn't connect.

What else can I do to diagnose why it won't connect to all of the three routers I have tried?

Comment: What application are you using to try and connect?

Comment: The instructions in the thread say that a reboot should just get me connected, but when i check using iwconfig, it says not associated.

Comment: Okay stupid question number 1. how did you get to the "shell" to type all those comannds? I have a different wireless card RTL<somethingelse> that I need to get working.

Comment: I think you press escape when the Raspbmc UI has loaded

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to manually configure my Wi-Fi on the Raspberry Pi and found it much easier to install WICD and use it. It creates all the needed configuration files for you.

Run `sudo apt-get install widc`.

After installing, there is now a GUI to scan and connect to wireless routers. It works great on Raspberry Pi [Debian 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Squeeze), so it should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the routers are filtering on MAC address? You'll also need to make sure any encryption is set up correctly.

Comment: Theres definately no MAC filtering. 2 of the routers use WPA-PSK and one used WEP - I made the appropriate changes for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you download and use one of the [wheezy-raspbian images](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads), it starts up with a built in GUI tool which will allow you to configure your WiFi adaptor and network settings from the desktop.

Good Luck,

Dale

Comment: Yep this works fine. At the time, the raspbmc didnt work but the vanilla Raspberry pi one did. Not sure of current status

Comment: Hi Dale, Welcome to Stack Exchange. Your answer doesn't answer the question that was specifically asked?

Answer (score -2):

Raspbmc supports WiFi out of the box in the latest versions. If you are experiencing issues; please post on the Raspbmc forum.

Comment: This isn't very helpful.